# convert from string to list in DAG airflow

Tags: python, scope, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am triggering my DAG in airflow using the following JSON:

```
{ "outcome": "A",
  "outcome_id": "B",
  "outcome_date": "C",
  "event_id": "D",
  "event_date": "E",
 ,"event_cat":["ABC", "DEF", "GHF"]}
```

I am using these passed values and assigning them to a variable like this in the DAG:

```
event_params = {
        'outcome': "{{ dag_run.conf['outcome'] }}",
        'outcome_id': "{{ dag_run.conf['outcome_id'] }}",
        'outcome_date': "{{ dag_run.conf['outcome_date'] }}",
        'event_id': "{{ dag_run.conf['event_id'] }}",
        'event_date': "{{ dag_run.conf['event_date'] }}"
        'event_cat': "{{ dag_run.conf['event_cat'] }}",
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that `event_cat` is getting converted into STRING. I tried doing this `eval("{{ dag_run.conf['event_cat'] }}")` to convert it back into LIST but this gives me error - `variable dag_run not found`.
Can you help me with a solution using which I can convert `event_cat` back to LIST of STRINGS ?

I saw in the LOG currently `event_cat` is being rendered as "["ABC", "DEF", "GHF"]" and I want it to be ["ABC", "DEF", "GHF"]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the list as

```
a = "['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHF']"
```

You can convert it with:

```
import ast
b = ast.literal_eval(a)
```

If you can't have the list with that format, you could pass it to the JSON as a single string

```
"event_cat": "ABC,DEF,GHF"
```

and then split it

```
"event_cat": "{{ dag_run.conf['event_cat'].split(',') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jinja-templated expressions are evaluated as strings. However, as of Airflow 2.1, a new parameter called [`render_template_as_native_obj`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects) was made available at the DAG level. This parameter will render a Jinja expression to a native Python type (e.g. list, dict, etc.). If you are using Airflow 2.1+, try using this parameter. You shouldn't require any `ast` or other string parsing.